# Population issue using Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

It's been a longtime i didn't use MongoDB, i am doing some queries and there is a basic situation i can't achieve:

```
//Works fine
Db['group'].findOne({ token: "token" })
.exec();

//Doesn't return the result
Db['group'].findOne({ "User.pseudo": "John", token: "token" })
.populate('User')
.exec();

//Return undefined
Db['group'].findOne({ User: { pseudo: "John" }, token: "token" })
.populate('User')
.exec();

var UserSchemaModel = {
  pseudo: { type: String, required: true }
};

var GroupSchemaModel = {
  User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  token: { type: String, required: true }
};
```

Maybe it's not possible to query this and we have to parse all the Users who match with token, then parse it with javascript to get the pseudo we are looking for (in another way, that we couldn't use `findOne()` in that case)...?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to declare your condition(s) into your `populate()` call:

```
Db['group'].findOne({ token: "token" })
.populate('User', '', { pseudo: "John"} )
.exec();
```